# Pull metadata from the contract document via docusign clm api

Tags: metadata, docusignapi

I'm trying to figure out how to pull metadata from the contract document which has been placed on the DocuSign clm folder.

Is there any way by which I can pull metadata from the contract document via DocuSign CLM API or any other alternatives to address this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign has the get Document by id, it returns all the information about that document, also there are different GET endpoints, but this one should works for you
[Get Document CLM](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/clm-api/reference/objects/documents/get/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).